# Why does UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification not get called for newlines and white space?

Tags: ios, nsnotifications

I am using RDRStickyKeyboardView for a (very) simple messaging feature in an iOS app. It is all working except that when I hit the enter key a bunch of times the frame gets all messed up and the keyboard ends up looking clipped. If I tap a letter key the views all suddenly sort them selves out. Looking at what is going on a bit the UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification notification is being triggered with letters but not white spaces even though the textview frame is being changed in both cases.

I'd love to know what is going on here but how do I trigger this notification manually as I can at least get this thing working then hopefully?

Thanks